# C++ Does Not Name A Type

Tags: c++, types, compiler-errors

I get confused when I get errors like these

I have

```
FxSmartPtr<FxStreamable> able(FcNew,stream->StreamInObject());

FxGlobalPair pair(id,able);
```

I get an error on `FxGlobalPair pair(id,able);` that is `able is not a type`.

I tried modifying to

```
FxGlobalPair pair(id,FxSmartPtr<FxStreamable>::able);
```

but I get an error that is `error: 'class FxSmartPtr<FxStreamable>::able' has not been declared`

What concept am I missing?

UPDATE: `typedef pair<FxID, FxSmartPtr<FxStreamable> > FxGlobalPair;`

UPDATE 2:

## Heading

Comment: Can we have information about the `FxGlobalPair` ?

Comment: The compiler cannot properly decide what the names are, types or variables. Neither can we, unless you show the lines preceding this, if any.

Comment: At a guess, you may be hitting the most vexing parse, so your first line is being treated as a function declaration.

Comment: @Bo I updated above to show the typedef.

Comment: Still not enough.  :-)  If `able` is an object and `id` is a type, there is an error. Or perhaps the compiler (like me) just cannot tell.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have found the [Most Vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

The problem is that

> FxSmartPtr able(FcNew,stream->StreamInObject());

may define a function named able, instead of a variable.